# Routing to static HTML pages, along with templated dynamic routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static

I've created a basic web app using Express, and provided a dynamic route such as:

```
app.get('/myroute/:user_id', function (req, res) {
    res.render('mytemplate');
});
```

This renders the EJS template "mytemplate.ejs" when the user visits `/myroute/15`

Now, I'd also like to create a second route `/staticroute` that transmits a static HTML page `somepage.html`.

What's the best way to do this? Should these static pages be served outside of Express? I've seen some related answers on StackOverflow, but they either use deprecated functionality or they do not support cacheing.

Comment: To serve static pages, I'd use nginx's [proxy_cache](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/caching/) in front of node.js. There is no "best way", use whatever that suits your style or needs.

Answer (score 2):

There's [`res.sendfile()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendfile) for such cases. Although if you don't need special routes for static files, you might look into using the `express.static` middleware instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `express.static` for images, css, and the like, but I do want special routes for a few pages.

Comment: Just to be really thorough, since Express 4.8 :
`deprecate res.sendfile -- use res.sendFile instead`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution you can try with memcached (too long to put into comments, I'd still recommend nginx's proxy_cache to avoid coding this below):

```
var Memcached = require('memcached'); // sudo apt-get install memcached
                                      // npm install memcached
var memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211'); // default
var ttl = 86400; // 24hrs time to live

function readContent(callback) { // async read with callback
    fs.readFile("./someIndex.html", function (err, content) {
        (err) ? callback(err) : callback(null, content);
    })
}

app.get('/someRoutes', function (req, res) {

  memcached.get('foo', function( err, content){ // get 'foo' from memcached
    if( err ) console.error( err ); // .get() error handling

    if( content ) { // data in memcached
      // render content and output
    } else { // data not in memcached

      readContent(function (err, myFile) { // try reading file
        if (myFile) { // file found, save to memcached & render
           memcached.set('foo', myFile, ttl, function( err, data ){
             if( err ) console.error( err ); // .set() error handling
           });
           // render myFile and output
        }
      }); // end readContent()

    } // end if-content-else-
  }); // end memcached.get()
}); // end app.get
```